# How can I make iOS background app notify based on location info

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement a location-baed navigation app on iOS.  I will have a device in my pocket and want it notifies when criteria are met based on location information, such as Google Maps navigation notifies when you make a turn on street.

I assume I can make it with CoreLocation and local notification.

Here are what I have done, expect and actually got.

- XCode Version 7.1 (7B91b) on OS X El Capitan 10.11.1
- In Xcode, File -> New -> Project -> iOS Application -> Single View Application
- Add CoreLocation framework to project
- Enable "Location updates" background mode
- Add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with value of "hello" to info.plist
- Leave ViewController.swift untouched
- Edit AppDelegate.swift as follows;

  ```
  import UIKit
  import CoreLocation

  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
      var window: UIWindow?
      lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager! = {
          let manager = CLLocationManager()
          manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
          manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
          manager.delegate = self
          manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
          return manager
      }()
      var lastNotifictionDate = NSDate()

      func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
          let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert], categories: nil)
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
          locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
          return true
      }

      func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
          // Do something interesting.
          // I make this function return immediately until 10sec passed after previous notification.
          let now = NSDate()
          if lastNotifictionDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(10).compare(now) == .OrderedDescending {
              //NSLog("Not yet")
              return
          }
          //NSLog("It's time")
          lastNotifictionDate = now

          // Fire local notification, without sound configured for simplicity.
          let notification = UILocalNotification()
          notification.alertBody = "Hello"
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
      }

      // ... other methods are untouched ...
  }
  ```

The app works on simulator as I expect, namely;

- Run the app in iPhone 5 Simulator and allow location and notification services
- Press home button (Shift-Command-H).
- In the simulator menu, Debug -> Location -> Free drive
- The app displays a local notification alert every 10sec

The app acts different on my device, iPhone 5 with iOS 9.1;

- Run the app via Xcode and allow location and notification services
- Pressed home button
- The device does not display notification alert either on home screen or notification center.
- Then, I tap the app icon on the device to bring the app foreground, opened the notification center and found two notifications.  I expect 5 notifications newly appear if I wait for 50 seconds, but no notification newly appear.

I understand Simulator behaves differently than the actual devices. For example, Simulator shows NSLog() and print() outputs on console during background, while the actual device does not.

I guess I did not configure something for devices or I am trying to do in unfeasible way, but I cannot find what it is.  Could you please tell me what is wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: So are you certain you acre actually receiving background updates on the device?

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Yes, I verified I am receiving location updates in background by adding `dates.append(NSDate())` in locationManager func.

Comment: So the problem is trying to schedule local notification?

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Yes. I should have clarified that.

Comment: Are you able to schedule then successfully on the foreground from the main thread? Also check permissions on the device to make sure it's allowed

Comment: @MitchellCurrie I can schedule notification in foreground and see it is displayed.  From the background, a notification is not displayed with `scheduleLocalNotification()` / `presentLocalNotificationNow()`. 
In The device settings, Allows Notifications, Show in Notification Center and Show on Lock Screen are on for the app. Alert style is "Banners".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting CLLocationManager's allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to true solved my problem.

```
manager.allowBackgroundLocationupdates = true
```

If it is false (default), updates stops when suspended.  Updates occur when foreground or background.